# Slow Down Fan Speed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fancontrol

I ran Windows 10 for a brief amount of time on my Lenovo ThinkPad T520 and the fan speed was by far more "normal" than it is on Ubuntu 18.04.

My question is, how can I slow down/normalize my fan speed when it's on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try this utility https://github.com/ichiriac/ubuntu-smart-fan, it's based on lm-sensors and it will manage the fan speed depending on how you want it to behave.

After calibrating the temperature and thresholds you will be able to run it as a daemon on your laptop

Comment: @loan Chiriac Thanks for posting this as a possible solution. However it doesn't work on a Dell-620 laptop running Ubuntu server 18.04, it says "Unable to load the manual fan mode. Try to run with sudo" when run as root. Ubuntu's fancontrol installs and runs but after running pwmconfig it runs the fan at full speed all the time :-(